# How can i add "where" to my request to db from java in JPQL?

Tags: java, jpql

How can i add "where" to my request to db from java in JPQL?

I have in service class call method from JpaRepository interface:

List t1List = T1Repository.findById(id) // this is not a PK

id - field from REST API request

And JpaRepository interface looks like:

```
public interface T1Repository extends JpaRepository<T1, Long> {

    @Query("select m from T1 m LEFT JOIN FETCH m.T2 where m.id= :id")
    List<T1> findById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

If i remove "where m.id= :id" it will response with all rows from all tabs, but with "where m.id= :id" - it response nothing

Help please

above all that try to use

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, do any of the rows in `T1` have that ID? And is the ID field in fact a string?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo sure, its id String in path and varchar in db

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry, didnt understand?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing
`where m.id= :id`

with this:
`where m.id= ?1`

Comment: Thnx, but it doesnt work